# Aerating bottled apple juice for cider

Tags: cider, aeration

I understand that disolved oxygen is good for yeast, and aeration is done near the time of pitching in beer making.  Does this rule hold true for bottled apple juice as it does for wort? Would apple juice be more prone to becoming stale with aeration than wort, or is it best to completely aerate juice as you would wort?

Edit: The juice I'm talking about would be pasturized, not fresh juice squeezed in the orchard.

Comment: If it's pasteurized, then no need to boil and no need to aerate, just pick one without preservatives as they can kill your yeast

Comment: But when the manufacturer pasturized, did they not remove all the oxygen?

Comment: I don't think so. Pasteurization usually is done by heating the juice to about 140-160F for 30 minutes, so not much oxygen loss there. I had healthy fermentation of apple juice cider with no aeration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you boil your wort, you are getting all that oxygen out of solution. If you are not boiling your apple juice you should have sufficent oxygen in there to conduct a good fermentation. I have done cider with bottled apple juice without oxygenating with good results.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. I aerated by shaking (before I saw your answer). Maybe you could add to your answer, if you know what risks to flavor would appear with aeration.  Or if aeration will not effect flavor in the final product.